# BackgroundWorker: is it dead once the DoWork() event handler is done?

Tags: .net, windows, multithreading, backgroundworker

What I'm getting at is once you complete your work with the DoWork() handler and then maybe do a RunWorkerCompleted(), can you then re-call RunWorkerAsync() and have it re-enter the DoWork() handler, or do you need to do another "new" operation and create a new BackgroundWorker?  Just wondering if any disposing or other cleanup is done after those things happen and now you no longer have a viable bg worker.

Comment: Just make sure you wait for the event before calling `RunWorkerAsync` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `RunWorkerAsync` all you like. You don't need to create a new `BackgroundWorker` object.

---

The only limitation is that you cannot call it while the `BackgroundWorker` is currently busy with an async operation already. So a common approach is this: say you call `RunWorkerAsync` when the user clicks a button. Then you disable the button, and re-enable it in the handler for the `RunWorkerCompleted` event:

```
void DoWorkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoWorkButton.Enabled = false;
    Worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Do some async operation.
}

void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // Do some updates.
    }
    finally
    {
        DoWorkButton.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```